# Automating a script in microsoft flow for excel to open hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, power-automate, office-scripts

First off, I am new to this all.  I have a macro which will open all of the hyperlinks I have in an excel file, but I would like to automate the process in microsoft flow/power automate.  I am not sure how to convert this to where it will work in office scripts.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub BatchOpenHyperLinks_Workbook()
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objSelectedRange As Excel.Range
Dim objHyperlink As Excel.Hyperlink

'Process each worksheet
For Each objWorksheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
For Each objHyperlink In objWorksheet.Hyperlinks
objHyperlink.Follow
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: I corrected one of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this VBA code can be converted in to Office Scripts code. But the objHyperlink.Follow won't work.
In this example, below, you can see how Excel Online uses URI's/URL's. It fetched the data at those links.
It doesn't open a new web page in your browser it fetches data instead.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const uri = 
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  const result = await fetch(uri);
  const json = result.json();
  console.log(json);
}
```